# Redirecting to the same View in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, view, swiftui

I'm experimenting with SwiftUI and I'm trying to make a very simple quiz app where you can learn a foreign language. I have a view that consists of a word in English, an image (emoji) and a translation. I'd like to add a button that would redirect me to this exact same view with new word to learn, without going deeper in navigation with `NavigationLink` and `NavigtaionView`. I'd still like to have a back button redirecting to my Home Screen, but I don't know if all this is possible in SwiftUI.

Code for the described view:

```swift
struct LearnView: View {
    var word: String
    var icon: String
    var translation: String

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 50) {
            SquareView(word: word, icon: icon)

            Text(translation).font(.largeTitle)

            // Button to next (same) view with new word
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where this button should take new word from? Have you some shared storage or model, etc? And what do you mean by "redirect"?

Comment: I have not shared any model, because I don't find it important or needed for the question. The new word will be selected randomly from json data and passed to the view. By "redirect" I mean repainting the same view with new data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this :

```
struct Word {
    var word: String
    var icon: String
    var translation: String
}

struct LearnView: View {

    @State var position = 0

    var words: [Word] = []

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 50) {
            SquareView(word: words[position].word, icon: words[position].icon)

            Text(words[position].translation).font(.largeTitle)

            Button("Next") {
                self.position += 1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a very clever solution! Didn't event think about it like that, thank you!